# mixed content error with custom font that doesn't exist anymore

Tags: wordpress, mixed-content

I have multilingual site, I install ssl recently(with let's encrypt), and used some plugin like really simple ssl, ssl insecure content fixer, http/https remover to fix mixed content error but none of these plugin did not fixed the problem. the I use google dev-tools, and see 6 mixed content error like this from 3 custom font, that doesn't exist anymore (i delete them):

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.safeducation.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://safeducation.com/wp-content/uploads/avia_fonts/type_fonts/yekan/yekan.ttf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I connected to host via ftp and ../wp-content/uploads/avia_fonts/type_fonts/ directory was empty. there was no other folder.

I downloaded the root directory to my host and search with atom, to find any http://saf... and change them in host but the problem still did not resolve

I'm confused because there was no any folder in ../wp-content/uploads/avia_fonts/type_fonts
can anyone help me, what should I do to fix this problem?
thanks for your time

Comment: To me that sounds as if there is a *link* to that address somewhere in your files (most likely either in the header.php file or in a stylesheet). Even if that file doesn't exist anymore, the (non-working) link is there and, being a `http` address, causes your problem. I could be wrong, but maybe that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using custom fonts and uploaded to theme options panel. just delete those fonts from theme option panel and re-upload one by one.

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of mix content error please paste the code into your wp-config.php file

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) && "https" == $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) {
$_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
}
```

Hope this will solve most of the issues.